# why am i get only last record of json array, which received from graphql with flutter?

Tags: mongodb, flutter, graphql

i have read all related question 
but there is no my solution. so please do not do any kind of things....
and be patient understand problem...

> my problem is similar to other but in case of flutter i cannot find any solution

My GraphQL result are this.

```
"user" : [
     {
        "name": "test6",
        "password": null,
        "lastMessageAt": null,
        "profilePhoto": null,
        "aboutme": null,
        "status": null,
        "firstLogin": false,
        "blockedAt": null
      },
      {
        "name": "asdhihgh",
        "password": null,
        "lastMessageAt": null,
        "profilePhoto": null,
        "aboutme": null,
        "status": null,
        "firstLogin": false,
        "blockedAt": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Anil Kumar Jat",
        "password": null,
        "lastMessageAt": null,
        "profilePhoto": null,
        "aboutme": null,
        "status": null,
        "firstLogin": false,
        "blockedAt": null
      }
    ]
```

but in flutter take data into
`List _userData = (response.data['user']) as List<dynamic>;`

after that build ListView using `ListView.Builder` than

i show only last record replicate in total records... means

```
name : Anil Kumar Jat
name : Anil Kumar Jat
name : Anil Kumar Jat
```

something like this.

My Code in Flutter are follow:

```
class NewChat extends StatelessWidget {
   String _allUserQuery {
      return """
      query {
        user {
            _id
            name
            mobileNo
            createdAt
            status
            aboutme
            profilePhoto
            isBlocked
          }
        }
    """;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text('Chat'))
      body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
          child: Query(
   options: QueryOptions(document: _allUserQuery),
   builder: (QueryResult result, {VoidCallback refetch}) {
   if (result.errors != null) {
       print(result.errors);
   }
   if (result.loading) {
       return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
   }
   if (result.data == null) {
        return Center(child: Text('No Data Found!'));
   }

    final List _userData = (result.data['user']) as List<dynamic>;

   return ListView.builder(
         itemCount: model.newUserList.length,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                   ListTile(
                     dense: true,
                     title: Text(_userData[index]['name'].toString()),
                     onTap: () {},
                   ),
                   Divider(
                     height: 1.0,
                   ),
              ],
           );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
 )
 )
}
```

Output like this:

[image: Output of above code like this]

Comment: share your code for the listbuilder, the problem must be there

Comment: i have provide code in question you can see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve me problem

> i have use this GraphQLClient setup

```
 ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
      GraphQLClient(
        cache: NormalizedInMemoryCache(
            dataIdFromObject: _typenameDataIdFromObject),
        link: link,
      ),
    );
    // ...
  }

  String _typenameDataIdFromObject(Object object) {
    if (object is Map<String, Object> &&
        object.containsKey('__typename') &&
        object.containsKey('id')) {
      return "${object['__typename']}/${object['id']}";
    }
    return null;
  }
```

then i receive last index of json object. but now i only return null

```
  String _typenameDataIdFromObject(Object object) {
    return null;
  }
```

then i have receive proper result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

[image]

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static Map<String, List<dynamic>> data = {
    "user": [
      {
        "name": "test6",
        "password": null,
        "lastMessageAt": null,
        "profilePhoto": null,
        "aboutme": null,
        "status": null,
        "firstLogin": false,
        "blockedAt": null
      },
      {
        "name": "asdhihgh",
        "password": null,
        "lastMessageAt": null,
        "profilePhoto": null,
        "aboutme": null,
        "status": null,
        "firstLogin": false,
        "blockedAt": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Anil Kumar Jat",
        "password": null,
        "lastMessageAt": null,
        "profilePhoto": null,
        "aboutme": null,
        "status": null,
        "firstLogin": false,
        "blockedAt": null
      }
    ]
  };
  List _userData = (data['user']) as List<dynamic>;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.grey,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('example'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _userData.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                  return new Text(_userData[index]["name"]);
                })),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes that is right, this code also working right in my end but the result receive from GraphQL and after that it not working properly. I have provide my code in question please see and tell me what is wrong!